# How do I trigger a script everytime a new row is filled?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have this script that **copies values** from one row and column **from one sheet* (Sheet2)* to a row and column on **another sheet* (Sheet1)*:

```
function copyBetweenSheets() {
    var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

    // Copy from Sheet2
    var copyThis = sheetFrom.getRange(sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 2, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 
    1).getValues();

    //Paste to Sheet1
    sheetTo.getRange(sheetTo.getLastRow()+1,1,string.length,1).setValues(copyThis);
    }
```

So Sheet2 is connected to a **Google Forms**, and **one row will be filled automatically** with values from the Form's answers once that Form is submitted.

So, is it possible to trigger the script above to **run every time a new row is filled after a Form is submitted**?

Thank You in advance. (Please let me know if you need more clarification)

Comment: If your question was solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onFormSubmit` since the data is from a form.

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  // sheet2 is where the form returns the submitted answers
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 

  // I modified your code here to work on the sample data below
  var recentSubmission = sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow(), 2, 1, sheet2.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, recentSubmission[0].length).setValues(recentSubmission);
}
```

Sheet2 (left) vs Sheet1 (right)

[image: sheet2 vs sheet1]

If you have any clarification, feel free to comment below.

Comment: you can also use onSubmit(). Not sure that onEdit will actually fire from a form submit.

Comment: I might update my answer using `onSubmit` later on. Thanks for the comment @J.G.

Comment: I already updated the answer @J.G., It is much simpler and is the best answer for the question, thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks it works! @NaziA, turns out you have to set a trigger 'On form submit' to trigger that function as well. :)

Comment: For clarification. If you set a "on form submit" trigger, you can call it anything you want. If you just call it "onSubmit" it should work automatically, like onEdit(). For posterity. Glad you got things working.